# Thunderbird + Gmail, has to send emails twice

Tags: email, gmail, sync, thunderbird, remote

I've configured Thunderbird to place a copy of my sent emails in my remote "sent" folder of my Gmail account as opposed to the local thunderbird one. This ensures I can completely take advantage of my imap synchronization.

And so whenever I send an email, it first sends one to the address list, then it sends a new one to my sent box, however doing this with large attachments seems like a waste of time and bandwidth. Do you guys know of any extension or a combination of a trick plus a Gmail filter that could automate this  in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this question,

in the Thunderbird Account Settings, under Copies & Folders,  un-tick "place a copy in" and under "BCC these email addresses" put your own Gmail address there.

Then go to your Gmail account, at the top click on "Create a filter" with these settings, "From" equals your own address, click Next, now tick these "Skip the Inbox", and "Apply the label [Imap/Sent]".

That should replicate the sent email in your sent box, without needing to send it twice. : )